# GoogleAppEngineLauncher deploy fails: appcfg.py has finished with exit code 0 ***

Tags: google-app-engine

My GoogleApp worked like a charm for a couple of weeks. For every update, I used GoogleAppEngineLauncher (from Mac OS X 10.10) to deploy it again. Never had problems.
Today, while I was deploying the app after a small fix, it was taking too much time, so I tried to abort and re-try. Terrible idea.
Now every time I try to deploy the app, it gives me this output:

```
 *** Running appcfg.py with the following flags:
--oauth2_credential_file=~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens update
12:25 AM Application: appname; version: 1
12:25 AM Host: appengine.google.com
12:25 AM Starting update of app: appname, version: 1
12:25 AM Getting current resource limits.
12:25 AM Scanning files on local disk.
12:25 AM Cloning 1 static file.
12:25 AM Cloning 6 application files.
12:25 AM Compilation starting.
12:25 AM Compilation completed.
12:25 AM Starting deployment.
12:25 AM Checking if deployment succeeded.
12:25 AM Deployment successful.
12:25 AM Checking if updated app version is serving.
12:25 AM Completed update of app: appname, version: 1
12:25 AM Uploading index definitions.
If deploy fails you might need to 'rollback' manually.
The "Make Symlinks..." menu option can help with command-line work.
*** appcfg.py has finished with exit code 0 ***
```

I used the Make Symlinks option but it didn't help. I also rollbacked manually, from cmd:

```
appcfg.py rollback Users/bran/Documents/Projects/appname
```

The output was:

```
12:54 AM Application: appname
12:54 AM Host: appengine.google.com
12:54 AM Rolling back the update.
```

I have found a couple of other related/similar questions, but the answers didn't solve my problem. Moreover, the other users didn't abort the deploying process, that is why I believe there is another reason why someone could get this error. I also tried to create another GoogleApp and copying the files, as well as uninstalling and re-installing GoogleAppEngineLauncher again. Same result. Please help, I don't know what else can I try to restore my previously working app. Maybe I didn't uninstall the GoogleAppEngineLauncher properly?
Also, I don't think the problem is in the app code, because I tried to revert the app back to its previous (deployed) status, but the error is still there.

**edit: I tried to use the Make Symlinks option again, and it gave me the following output/error:**

```
*** Running appcfg.py with the following flags:
--oauth2_credential_file=~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens update
07:17 PM Application: appname; version: 1
07:17 PM Host: appengine.google.com
07:17 PM Starting update of app: astribot, version: 1
07:17 PM Getting current resource limits.
2016-08-03 19:18:17,605 ERROR appcfg.py:2411 An error occurred     processing file '': EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590). Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
run_file(__file__, globals())
File "google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
File     "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5497, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-   default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5488, in main
result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2966, in Run
self.action(self)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 5144, in __call__
return method()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3876, in Update
self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3929, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, APP_YAML_FILENAME)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3814, in UpdateVersion
return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2401, in DoUpload
self.error_fh)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 497, in GetResourceLimits
resource_limits.update(_GetRemoteResourceLimits(logging_context))
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 467, in _GetRemoteResourceLimits
yaml_data = logging_context.Send('/api/appversion/getresourcelimits')
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1709, in Send
result = self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **kwargs)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 246, in Send
url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 569, in new_request
redirections, connection_type)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1584, in request
(response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1332, in _request
(response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1268, in _conn_request
conn.connect()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1014, in connect
self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation, self.ca_certs)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 911, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
If deploy fails you might need to 'rollback' manually.
The "Make Symlinks..." menu option can help with command-line work.
*** appcfg.py has finished with exit code 1 ***
```

Comment: `exit code 0` usually means success, a **non-zero** code is something to watch out for... Did you check if the updated app runs fine?

Comment: Unfortunately the app doesn't work since that moment :( It is actually a Telegram Bot with a small AI described inside the main.py file. The bot is not responding to any command, it's like dead.